# PHP mysql Select query calling more than specified data

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working and testing with queries, and I came across this issue which I don't understand why it's happening.

I have this code:

```
<?php
        $query = "
    SELECT sc.course_code
         , c.course_name 
      FROM student_course sc
         , courses  c
     WHERE sc.course_code= 'MC 101' 
       AND sc.id_num='A0001'
    ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        ?>
     <p> <h4 style="w3-wide"> <?php echo $row["course_name"];?> </h3>
           <h4 style="w3-wide"><?php echo $row["course_code"];?>  </h3>
         <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-theme-d2 w3-margin-bottom" style = "float:right"><i></i><a href="schedule mc101.php"> View Course</a></button></p>
    <br>
```

And based on what I know, it should call a single data which satisfies the conditions `student_course.course_code = 'MC 101'`  and `student_course.id_num='A0001'` which should only be

```
Statistics in Computing
MC 101
```

However, this is what I'm getting:

[image: What I get instead]

The course names are correct, but all of them have the same code. Does anyone know why this is happening? Much appreciated!

Comment: if it show three rows  , you got three rows with that criteria. See if there is an id in your table, so that you can identify the rows to check it out.

Comment: Alright, they do have the same criteria which is the `id_num`, but if I remove that, it still shows the same thing, except that they are doubled with the same course code, MC 101.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Your next problem is that your student_course, courses makes a cross join and so use an INNER JOINbetween both table and in the ON Clause you put bith joining columns

Comment: Okay, so I have tried using `JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`, but the three subjects are still displaying the same course codes. Could there be anywhere else that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a join condition,
it must me something like `ON sc.course_id = c.id`

```
SELECT sc.course_code, c.course_name 
  FROM student_course sc
  JOIN courses c ON sc.course_id = c.id
 WHERE sc.course_code= 'MC 101' 
   AND sc.id_num='A0001'
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you! However, could you explain how the `ON` clause works? I'm not familiar with it.